# Hash CSS and JS file load with the same value for a long time, makes sense to avoid caching?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working in a application and I am seeing JS and CSS files loaded as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.livequery.js?1474472108"></script>
<link href="/js/jquery.cookiebar.min.css?1474472239" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I am not wrong this is used for browser caching stuff. I am Right? The digits after `?` are built using [filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) which is the modification time.

If the file loaded hasn't been modified from the last month and will continue without being modified for one more year, makes sense to add the same value all the time?

Comment: Please **DO NOT MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE** without read properly, I am asking `If the file loaded hasn't been modified from the last month and will continue without being modified for one more year, makes sense to add the same value all the time?` !!!!

Comment: If you have a system in place that can set the cache-buster code to file version or when it was last changed, then yes, it makes sense to use it. It doesn't matter how long it will remain the same in the future.

Comment: I would suggest that you change the post title to what the actual question is to avoid getting duplicate close votes.

Answer (score -2):

? is what is before the first parameter in a URI, in this case it means the version of the file